# Hitting a nullPointerExecption in my android project

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception

Hi Iam trying to make a chat app. In this process Iam trying to retrieve messages stored in database but Iam getting a Null Object reference exception.

The code I used to add messages to database is:

```
    img_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            String msg = text_send.getText().toString();
            if(!msg.equals(""))
                sendMessage(fuser.getUid(), currUserId, msg);
            else
                Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this, "Enter Something", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
       });


  private void sendMessage(String sender,String receiver,String message)
  {
    DatabaseReference reference = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    HashMap<String,Object>hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("sender",sender);
    hashMap.put("receiver",receiver);
    hashMap.put("message",message);

    reference.child("Chats").push().setValue(hashMap);

}
```

NOTE:The above part of code is working fine. My database is getting updated correctly every time I send message.

After this part I tried to display messages of users, using the following code

```
     DatabaseReference chatref = 
     FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chats");
     ArrayList<String> userchats = new ArrayList<>();

     listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
     final ArrayAdapter <String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> 
     (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,userchats);
     listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

     chatref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, 
        @Nullable String s) {

            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(value);
                message = object.getString("message");
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            userchats.add(message);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, 
         @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, 
        @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
        });
```

When I ran the app at this moment Iam getting error and my stacktrace is as follows:

```
         Process: com.kcw.firebasebasics, PID: 10943
         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
         'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object 
         reference at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.
         createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:401)
         at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369)
         at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
         at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1875)
```

Finally a picture of my database:

[image: picture of database]

Comment: This code actually worked for the first time but then I deleted some messages from database then after it is throwing such exception I tried re installing application and logging in again but none helped

Comment: Is it not the " String value = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();" Whats causing the error? 
Since your log seems to say that it is.

Comment: Yes it is the one causing error but all seems fine with that line , where exactly is it pointing to a null pointer exception

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @alex mamo I am getting error on this line 
String value = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()

Comment: @jayanth What is the exact error that you get when using Peter's answer?

Comment: @alexmamo the same thing which i got earlier      Process: com.kcw.firebasebasics, PID: 10943
         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
         'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object 
         reference at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.
         createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:401)

Comment: Will be helpful for you if I'll provide you an answer for getting the value of `message` property, using a `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`?

Comment: please do it Iam tring another sources but each time I am facing same null pointer exepction issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
String value = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
```

into this:

```
String value = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue(String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `chatref` refer to the "Chats" key witch is not a String. That´s maybe why you get the

> 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object

You should parse the dataSnapshot into a class like this example

```
Comment comment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
```

And the `Comment` class have the `message` `receiver` `Sender` variables

Check this [Work with Lists of Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data) from Firebase doc

And finally here is the [Firebase Android Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0) showing how to create a complete chat app called Friendly Chat

Comment: Please tell me how to add data from comment to message, sender, receiver. Iam new to firebase and Iam unable to find resources that I can understand please help

Comment: I updated my answer with specifics, you must go trough a codelab because it will be much easier to understand this